# Want to read words from txt file and insert that word in a list (p_words) which have character 'p' in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

```
with open("school_prompt.txt" , "r") as word:
p_words = []
for w in word.readlines():
    value = w.split(' ')
    if value.startswith('p'):
        p_words.append(value)
print(p_words)
```

Want to read words from txt file and insert that word in a list (p_words) which have character 'p' in it

Comment: This seems like a homework question and you haven't attempted to complete the task at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a second loop to look at the contents of your `split`, which will generate a list of objects, so something like:

```
with open("school_prompt.txt" , "r") as word:
p_words = []
for w in word.readlines():
    for value in w.split(' '):
        if value.startswith('p'):
            p_words.append(value)
print(p_words)
```

You might be optionally interested in `if 'p' in value:` ranther than `if value.startswith('p'):`, in case you're really looking for words with 'p' in it, rather than having a 'p' at the beginning only.

Comment: I need all that words which have character p in it